# 'one of the best stylists and most lucid minds'

Tags: lists

"White is one of the best stylists and most lucid minds in this country."

Do you like this sentence? ...'one of the best' -X- and 'most' -Y- ... I guess what it boils down to is my unfamiliarity with listing 'one of the' adjective-this, different-adjective-that, etcetera. Thoughts?

Comment: Sounds fine to me. You're using parallelism to express "White is one of the best stylists in this country," and "White is one of the most lucid minds in this country."

Comment: What's the question - whether I like it?

Answer (score -1):

That's right, you are using 2 superlative adjectives there
White is one of the best stylists and one of the most lucid minds in this country."+
You just don't need to mention one of the again

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to have better formatting and proper grammar? When you click "edit," there will be some tips on the right side of the screen.